# How to Determine Sufficient Time for Melanoma Survivor to Be Considered Low Risk?

Tags: bioinformatics, pathology, literature

Regarding melanoma, how do we determine the minimum amount of time that a patient is disease free for them to be considered low risk? We are attempting to do survival analysis on RNASeq data from melanoma patients.

We are at the stage where we need to adjust the threshold that dictates how long a "Disease Free" patient needs to be disease free to be considered a low risk case. Is 5 years a good parameter or is it too conservative? 
Academic sources for protocols, or similar examples are encouraged.

Comment: From undergraduate courses of cancer, the 5 year survival rate is common. However I have no idea where that value comes from.

Comment: Do you vaguely remember any literature that you can point me to?